# Classification with Keras: prediction and multiclass

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I implement a multiclass classifier with keras. 
My problem now is to make predictions, because I obtain an error. I believe that it is related with the prediction part of the code.

The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np  
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, img_to_array, load_img  
from keras.models import Sequential  
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense  
from keras import applications  
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical 

from PIL import Image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import math

%matplotlib inline

# dimensions of our images.  
img_width, img_height = 150, 150  

top_model_weights_path = 'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'  
train_data_dir = 'data/train'  
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'  

epochs = 30  
batch_size = 16

def save_bottleneck_features():

    model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')  
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)  

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height), \
                                            batch_size=batch_size, class_mode=None, shuffle=False)  

    n_train_samples = len(generator.filenames)  
    n_classes = len(generator.class_indices)
    print("Number of train files = {}".format(n_train_samples))
    print("Number of classes = {}".format(n_classes))

    predict_size_train = int(math.ceil(n_train_samples / batch_size))  

    bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(generator, predict_size_train)  

    np.save('bottleneck_features_train.npy', bottleneck_features_train) 

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height), \
     batch_size=batch_size, class_mode=None, shuffle=False)  

    n_validation_samples = len(generator.filenames)  

    predict_size_validation = int(math.ceil(n_validation_samples / batch_size))  

    bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(generator, predict_size_validation)  

    np.save('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', bottleneck_features_validation)  


def train_top_model():
    datagen_top = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  
    generator_top = datagen_top.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height),\
                                                    batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', \
                                                    shuffle=False)  

    n_train_samples = len(generator_top.filenames)  
    n_classes = len(generator_top.class_indices)  

    # load the bottleneck features saved earlier  
    train_data = np.load('bottleneck_features_train.npy')  

    # get the class lebels for the training data, in the original order  
    train_labels = generator_top.classes  

    # convert the training labels to categorical vectors  
    train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=n_classes)

    generator_top = datagen_top.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height),\
                                                    batch_size=batch_size, class_mode=None, shuffle=False)  

    n_validation_samples = len(generator_top.filenames)  

    validation_data = np.load('bottleneck_features_validation.npy')  

    validation_labels = generator_top.classes  
    validation_labels = to_categorical(validation_labels, num_classes=n_classes) 

    model = Sequential()  
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))  
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))  
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))  
    model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='sigmoid'))  

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',  
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])  

    history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,\
                        validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))  

    model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)  

    (eval_loss, eval_accuracy) = model.evaluate(validation_data, validation_labels, \
                                                batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)

    print("[INFO] accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(eval_accuracy * 100))  
    print("[INFO] Loss: {}".format(eval_loss))
    return model
```

To execute the program we do:

```
save_bottleneck_features()
model = train_top_model()
```

when I try to make a prediction, using the following code:

```
img_path = 'image_test/bird.jpg'  

# predicting images
img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
x = img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
print (classes)
```

it gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-c3652addeabc> in <module>()
      8 
      9 images = np.vstack([x])
---> 10 classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
     11 print (classes)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py in predict_classes(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
   1016             A numpy array of class predictions.
   1017         """
-> 1018         proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
   1019         if proba.shape[-1] > 1:
   1020             return proba.argmax(axis=-1)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
    911         if not self.built:
    912             self.build()
--> 913         return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    914 
    915     def predict_on_batch(self, x):

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1693         x = _standardize_input_data(x, self._feed_input_names,
   1694                                     self._feed_input_shapes,
-> 1695                                     check_batch_axis=False)
   1696         if self.stateful:
   1697             if x[0].shape[0] > batch_size and x[0].shape[0] % batch_size != 0:

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    142                             ' to have shape ' + str(shapes[i]) +
    143                             ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 144                             str(array.shape))
    145     return arrays
    146 

ValueError: Error when checking : expected flatten_8_input to have shape (None, 7, 7, 512) but got array with shape (1, 150, 150, 3)
```

Comment: You're getting always the same error messages. Read them. Your model (the one that starts with `Flatten`) is expecting that you data `X` be shaped as `(BatchSize, 7, 7, 512)`, but you are trying to predict with your `X` shaped as `(BatchSize, 150, 150, 3)`.

Comment: I now that my tensors have the wrong shape. However I don't know how to solve the problem, because I believe that the problem is in the predict function. In fact I don't really understand how do I feed the DNN. This problem is very common (it is present in many places) but with few solutions.

Comment: The problem is clearly how the input/output tensors are created. This problem can only be solved if we have a clear understanding of what is your data and what is the expected output. How many models do you have? One or two? What are bottleneck features? Is your model supposed to receive an image or the output of another model? Can you list each of your models and explain in words what is the input and the output of each of them? That would make it a lot easier to understand what do you want to achieve with your code.

Comment: Unfortunately the conversion of the images into matrices is something that is not very clear to me. As far as I know, it should always be a matrix of rank 3, but I define the *generator* I can't see what is inside. For example, in the previous error I feed the system with a tensor of rank 4 with shape (1, 150, 150, 3), that it something that I understand because it is an image of size 150x150 with three channels. However the system is expecting something like (Something, 7, 7, 512) that I don't understand.

Comment: That is the shape you defined for your model: `model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))` --- That means that `train_data` is not an image, it's something else. --- And it's loaded from "bottleneck features", what is "bottleneck features?" they're not images as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer.
In order to predict the class of an image, we need to run it through the same pipeline as before.

The prediction function must be:

```
image_path = 'image_test/bird.jpg'  

orig = cv2.imread(image_path)  

print("[INFO] loading and preprocessing image...")  
image = load_img(image_path, target_size=(img_width, img_height))  
image = img_to_array(image)  

# important! otherwise the predictions will be '0'  
image = image / 255  

image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

# build the VGG16 network  
model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')  

# get the bottleneck prediction from the pre-trained VGG16 model  
bottleneck_prediction = model.predict(image)  

# build top model  
model = Sequential()  
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=bottleneck_prediction.shape[1:]))  
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))  
model.add(Dropout(0.5))  
model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))  

model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)  

# use the bottleneck prediction on the top model to get the final classification  
class_predicted = model.predict_classes(bottleneck_prediction) 

inID = class_predicted[0]  

class_dictionary = generator_top.class_indices  

inv_map = {v: k for k, v in class_dictionary.items()}  

label = inv_map[inID]  

# get the prediction label  
print("Image ID: {}, Label: {}".format(inID, label))
```